# SQL Server trigger does not update fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, database-trigger, sql-server-2017

I am a newbie at SQL server triggers and have tried to write a trigger that does not do what i want. I am sure there is a obvious reason to why, but i can´t see the problem? Is there anyone of you more skilled at this that see any obvioius mistake(s) i have done i my trigger script?
What happens when table booking is inserted or updated is nothing really, but i had for example hoped that column FareToCollect had changed to 0 when column FareTypeID = 'FAKT'.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Fare] 
   ON  [dbo].[Booking] 
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
   AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @bo_id int
Declare @leg_id int
Declare @fare_sum real
Declare @Payment_Type_Id varchar

Select @bo_id = inserted.bookingid from inserted
Select @fare_sum = inserted.fareamount from inserted
Select @leg_id = ba.LegId from BookingActivity ba inner join BookingLegs bl on bl.LegId=ba.LegId where bl.BookingId=@bo_id and bl.LegNum=0
Select @Payment_Type_Id = inserted.PaymentTypeId from inserted

IF  @Payment_Type_Id = 'FAKT'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Booking
        SET FareToCollect = 0
        FROM inserted ins
        INNER JOIN booking bo on ins.BookingId=bo.BookingId 

        UPDATE BookingActivity
        SET FareAmount = 0
        FROM BookingActivity 
        WHERE BookingActivity.LegId=@leg_id
    END;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Booking
        SET FareToCollect = @fare_sum
        FROM inserted ins
        INNER JOIN booking bo on ins.BookingId=bo.BookingId

        UPDATE BookingActivity
        SET FareAmount = @fare_sum
        FROM BookingActivity
        WHERE BookingActivity.LegId=@leg_id 
    END

END
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using, which is presumably SQL Server.

Comment: Triggers are SET based.  Not RBAR (row by agonizing row) based.  You need to refactor to be set based.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Your trigger is just broken.  The brokenness starts on the first line of code:

```
select @bo_id = inserted.bookingid from inserted;
```

This assumes that `inserted` has only one row.  But that is NOT a valid assumption.  In SQL Server (unlike most other databases) triggers are *set*-based.  The `inserted` (and `deleted`) "table" references can have multiple rows.

Your entire trigger needs to be rewritten taking this into account.  For most operations, `inserted` and `deleted` can be used in set-based logic.  Under some circumstances, you might need to walk through each value using a cursor or other mechanism.